# Cant return a string in c++?

Tags: c++, string, return

I have string name in my header file, when I want to return it using the `getName()` method in the cpp source file, I get this error.                `"error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'int' in return|"`.

How can i change the `getName()` method to properly return the string name variable? I'm new to c++ thanks. (PROBLEM LIES WITH LAST METHOD IN Person.cpp)

Header File:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H
#include <string>

class Person{

private:

    int age;
    std::string name;

public:

    Person();   //constructors
    Person(int x, std::string y);
    Person(int x);
    Person(std::string y);
    Person(std::string y, int x);

    setAge(int x); //set functions
    setName(std::string x);

    getAge(); //set functions
    getName();




};
#endif
```

Person.cpp`(PROBLEM IS WITH LAST (getName())` method:

```
#include "Person.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//Constructor Functions

Person::Person(){ //constructor #1, constructor for no set parameters

}//end of Constructor #1

Person::Person(int x, std::string y){ //constructor #2, constructor for when 
both int age and string name are given

}//end of Constructor #2

Person::Person(int x){ //constructor #3, constructor for when only int age 
is given

}//end of Constrictor #3

Person::Person(std::string x){ //constructor #4, constructor for when only 
string name is given

}//end of Constructor #4

Person::Person(std::string y, int x){ //constructor #6, constructor that 
uses same parameters as constructor #2 but has order reversed

}//end of Constructor #6

//end of Constructor Functions


//Set Functions

Person::setAge(int x){//sets int age to the int x parameter

}//end of setAge function
Person::setName(std::string x){//sets string name to the string x parameter

}//end of setName function

//end of Set Functions


//Get Functions

Person::getAge(){//returns int age
return age;
}//end of getAge

Person::getName(){//returns string name
//PROBLEM IS HERE **********************************************
return name;
}
```

Comment: You seem to miss the concept of the return type in every place.

Comment: You need to specify the return types in the member functions.

Comment: Read through this tutorial on C++ classes: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Comment: You should explicitly declare the return type. By default it will assume int.

Comment: Thanks, problem resolved

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the functions' return types in both the declarations:

```
void setAge(int x);
void setName(std::string x);

int getAge();
std::string getName();
```

...and the definitions:

```
int Person::getAge(){
    return age;
}

std::string Person::getName(){
    return name;
}
```

For functions this trivial, it's pretty common to define the function directly inside the class definition though:

```
class Person{

private:

    int age;
    std::string name;

public:
    // ...

    void setAge(int x) { age = x; }
    void setName(std::string x) { name = x; }

    int getAge() { return age; }
    std::string getName() { return age; }
};
```

Your `get` functions should normally also be marked `const`:

```
    int getAge() const { return age; }
    std::string getName() const { return age; }
```

This allows them to be invoked on `const` objects.

From the looks of things, you should also read about [pseudo-classes and quasi-classes](http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you should notify you return value to 'get' functions.
Like this:

```
int getAge() { return age; }
std::string getName() { return age; }
```